# Как сделать пароль под AES 256?

Tags: c#, защита, криптография, aes

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста как сделать 256 битный пароль под AES, на основе пользовательского пароля, длина которого может быть совсем разная.

То-есть если я сейчас буду шифровать текст, с `KeyString = "helloworld"`, то вылезит ошибка, что пароль не подходит по длине, то-есть 256 битам. Что придумать с паролем?

```
        public static string EncryptString(string message, string KeyString, string IVString)
        {
            byte[] Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);

            byte[] IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVString);

            string encrypted = null;
            RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
            rj.Key = Key;
            rj.IV = IV;
            rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        sw.Write(message);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                    cs.Close();
                }
                byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
                encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);

                ms.Close();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A file error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                rj.Clear();
            }
            return encrypted;
        }
```

Comment: Можно хеш от пароля взять подходящей длины

Comment: вообще то если я не ошибаюсь за приделами США запрещено использовать 256 байтовая кодирования

Comment: @VardanVardanyan почему?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, на AES не работают никакие ограничения. На RC2 были ограничения, про них написано в вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy я это помню из практике как то в офисе мне не дали использовать 256 байтовый тип  шифрования по причине что было введено какое то ограничения со стороны Агентство национальной безопасности США ,но конкретно какие я не знаю не искал и не читал ;)  как то так

Comment: Дополните нулями или пробелами до нужной длинны:)

Comment: @nick_n_a была такая идея и попробовал, но не помогало и тем более что делать если пароль будет больше 256, вы скажите тоже обрезать, оно будет наверное работать, но мне кажется это как-то не правильно с точки зрения безопасности, потому-что мне кажется много будет схожостей паролей, то-есть например если исходный пароль будет `qweeee..ещё 246 ..erty`, то `qweeee..ещё 246 ..ertylolkek` грубо говоря будет проходить проверку, короче конкретная дыра будет ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать правильно, существуют Password Based Encryption, в которых предусмотрены наборы алгоритмов (блочные шифры, режим шифрования, хеш функция, количество итераций), которые на основе только пароля шифруют данные. Используется это, например в PKCS #12. Но, насколько я знаю, в C# нет классов для работы с этим.

Если делать проще, можно взять любую хеш-функцию, которая выдает 256-битный хеш (например SHA256) или хеш функцию, с хешом длиннее 256 бит, и обрезать конечный хеш. Для повышения безопасности (если пользователь вдруг решит использовать сильно простой пароль), можно взять хеш некоторое количество итераций (например несколько тысяч раз):

```
key = sha256(sha256(....sha256(pwd)...))
```

Comment: Есть Rfc2898DeriveBytes в .NET для этого.

Comment: Да, действительно, это как раз то.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов чёто в первый раз про это слышу, не я лучше с sha по работаю, тем более он уже встречался мне и я много про него слышал, типо он лютый :D Но плюс всё равно поставлю за совет, спасибо.

Comment: Ответ некорректный, формально типа верен, но по криптоканонам так нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

> Скажите пожалуйста как сделать 256 битный пароль

Не пароль, а ключ - разница есть.

Рекомендованный и православный способ описан в [RFC-2898](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)

Грубо говоря вам надо использовать алгоритм [PBKDF2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)

На гитхабе валяется много имплементаций этого алгоритма для C#